# Environment USER and USERNAME in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, sudo, environment-variables

I stumbled across a difference in the way `sudo` alters `env` variables between CentOS 7.3 and CentOS 7.4.

Here is a script I have run on CentOS 7.3 and 7.4:

```
#!/bin/bash
env | grep USER

sudo env | grep USER

unset USERNAME

env | grep USER

sudo env | grep USER
```

On CentOS 7.3 this gives (formatted):

```
USER=gncs
USERNAME=gncs

[sudo] password for gncs: 
USERNAME=gncs
USER=root
SUDO_USER=gncs

USER=gncs

USER=root
USERNAME=root
SUDO_USER=gncs
```

On CentOS 7.4 this gives (formatted):

```
USER=gncs
USERNAME=gncs

[sudo] password for gncs: 
USERNAME=gncs
USER=gncs    # !!!
SUDO_USER=gncs

USER=gncs

USER=root
USERNAME=root
SUDO_USER=gncs
```

Why is `USER` still `gncs` when I run `env` with `sudo` on CentOS 7.4?
Once I unset the `USERNAME` variable the behavior is the same.

I came across this problem when running the following python program with `sudo`:

```
import getpass
getpass.getuser()
```

Under Centos 7.3 it returns `root`, under 7.4 `gncs`.
I believe this is related to the environment variables mentioned above.

Additional information:

```
$ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.19p2
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.19p2
Sudoers file grammar version 45
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.19p2

$ sudo grep -r env /etc/sudo*
[sudo] password for gncs: 
/etc/sudoers:# is already set when the the env_reset option is enabled, so
/etc/sudoers:# env_reset is disabled or HOME is present in the env_keep list.
/etc/sudoers:Defaults    env_reset
/etc/sudoers:Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
/etc/sudoers:Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
/etc/sudoers:Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
/etc/sudoers:Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
/etc/sudoers:Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
/etc/sudoers:# Adding HOME to env_keep may enable a user to run unrestricted
/etc/sudoers:# Defaults   env_keep += "HOME"
```

Comment: Don't rely on environment variables. In this case, use `id` with the appropriate flags instead.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify why this is important to me.

Comment: `getpass.getuser()` [seems to be using environment variables first, and the password database as a fallback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html). IMHO that's a broken design as environment variables may be set to whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! How would you suggest me to write this piece of Python code instead? like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2899055/927094)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no Python programmer.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo grep -r env /etc/sudo*`? What's the version of `sudo`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I added the requested information

Comment: See the `env_keep += ... USERNAME ...`

Comment: Interestingly, `sudo grep -r env /etc/sudo*` gives the same output in CentOS 7.3.
But: the sudo versions are different: in CentOS 7.3 it is `Version: 1.8.6p7
Release: 23.el7_3` (`sudo --version` returns `invalid option -- '-'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the `sudo` program has changed from CentOS 7.3 to 7.4.
In addition, I learned that in the `getpass` Python module the function `getuser` uses environment variables first, which is not optimal.

To solve my original question I opted for the following piece of Python code which appears to have the desired behavior.

```
import os
import pwd
pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_name
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been changes to the sudo program in CentOS 7.4. The question really is the user wants to get the OS username in a python code. 
All the methods seem to be dependent on the environment variables so it might not be working in all scenarios.

You could try these options to make it at least work on **CentOS 7.3** and **7.4**

```
import commands
username = commands.getoutput("logname")
print username
```

---

```
import os
os.getlogin()
```

**Note**: *I would have added this as a comment but I have just started answering questions and do not have enough reputation to add it as a comment.*